# Android app becomes slow after adding Firebase Analytics and Crash Reporting

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-crash-reporting

Before adding firebase analytics my app worked really fast. It has a lot of request which are sequential. 
However, as soon as I added firebase analytics my app's internet requests froze and I got a lot of logs which consume time for no purpose.

```
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/my.project.-1/lib/arm64
W/art: Verification of void my.project.App.<init>() took 133.425ms
D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.
D/FirebaseApp: Initialized class com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.
V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: com.google.android.gms signature not valid.  Found: <Some big sequence of characters>
I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
D/ChimeraCfgMgr: Reading stored module config
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.crash:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.crash:2
D/ChimeraFileApk: Primary ABI of requesting process is arm64-v8a
D/FirebaseCrashReceiverServiceImpl: onCreate
I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.flags, version >= 1
```

This is quite important, because I wait about 5-6 seconds until my own requests start to execute.

Comment: Rustam, the logcat that you posted has only single Firebase Analytics entry. There is nothing disturbing in the log so its difficult to tell what's going on. Can you please 1. Enable Firebase Analytics debug logs (https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events#view_events_in_the_android_studio_debug_log), 2. Try using only Firebase Analytics w/o Firebase Crash reporting to isolate the issue. If possible provide more logcat optput and include timestamps. Just the messages are not sufficient to diagnose performance problems.

Comment: Rustam, any chance that your app is crashing repeatedly in a background thread that you have not noticed? It will cause Crash reporting to consume resources processing the crashes and can have significant slowdown effect on everything in the app.

Comment: djabi, thanks a lot, I don't know why but my alarm manager was the cause of this problem And apparently it really was repeatedly crashing in background

Comment: Any news here? I have the same problem, my app only shows the layout after firebase is succesfully initialized, and that takes ages on slow internet

Comment: @Jason well, as I wrote, my app was slow because I started a service every minute with alarm manager. And it crashed when I closed the app. To avoid this problem I just put one statement in try catch block. Probably, you have something like this

Comment: I've got no service running, when I start a new activity that new activity just laggs, although there is only 2x a 400KB image and 2x and 300KB image shown

Comment: me too. same problem